# Lindeberg-Feller CLT follows from Martingale CLT?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I've been studying about central limit theorems, in particular the Lindeberg-Feller CLT and other extensions. In most textbooks and sources online the martingale central limit theorem comes as an improvement, but it is not clear to me how it implies the Lindeberg-Feller CLT? Can someone shed some light on this or point to a discussion? Thanks!

Comment: Which part of your question is not covered by [this](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/383/Lindeberg.pdf)?

Comment: With the notations from there, I was wondering for instance if the conditions from Theorem 4, with (12) replaced by $E[\max_{i}{|\xi_{n,i}|}] \to 0$, imply the Lindeberg conditions from page 3.

Comment: Sorry but your question needs to be made *much* more specific. Please explain, and include in the question, the precise problems you have.